# Select arrays contain on other arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I need select the arrays that be contains for other arrays on PostgreSql

I tried using:

```
select * from test.cruce
where calle <@ direccion
```

but, the result is zero.

when i use

```
select * from test.cruce
where calle && direccion
```

### calle ; direccion

```
{CAMILO,TORRES,1000,1099}";"{Cosquin,1000}
{LOS,ALELIES,300,399}";"{Las,Camelias,300}
```

the second case is fail.

Some idea?

Comment: Can you provide also the expected result? I didn't quite understand your issue.

Comment: I need comparated a array with other, and select the array that contains all or more coincidences.

Comment: Well, then `select * from cruce where calle && direccion;` should already suffice, since the value `1000` can be found in both columns of the first record and the same with `300` in the second record. Isn't it what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @JimJones I need comparated "{EL,URUBITINGA,600,619}";"{El,Urubitinga,600}", in this case is correct this query, [0][1][2][3] its contains in the second arrays, no only one register.

Comment: can you try this? `select * from cruce where lower(calle::text)::TEXT[] @> lower(direccion::text)::TEXT[]` I believe your problem is related to case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing array elements that have the "same" text values, but written with a different case, e.g. *URUBITINGA* and *Urubitinga*.
First you have to set both elements to the same case and only then you can compare the arrays using `@>`.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cruce (calle TEXT[],direccion TEXT[]);
INSERT INTO cruce VALUES ('{CAMILO,TORRES,1000,1099}'::TEXT[],'{Cosquin,1000}'::TEXT[]),
                         ('{LOS,ALELIES,300,399}'::TEXT[],'{Las,Camelias,300}'::TEXT[]),
                         ('{EL,URUBITINGA,600,619}'::TEXT[],'{El,Urubitinga,600}'::TEXT[]);

SELECT * FROM cruce
WHERE LOWER(calle::TEXT)::TEXT[] @> LOWER(direccion::TEXT)::TEXT[];

          calle          |      direccion      
-------------------------+---------------------
 {EL,URUBITINGA,600,619} | {El,Urubitinga,600}
(1 Zeile)
```

Keep in mind that there is a certain overhead of casting arrays to `TEXT`, `LOWER` and then casting them back to `TEXT[]`.

Comment: Thx, I will analyze the result, but at first glance, itseem to be correct